# Как реализовать "триггер" при столкновении игрока к другому объекту(коробке) с другой областью столкновения?

Tags: python, pygame

Есть игра:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import sys

from pygame.transform import scale

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

motion = "stop"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512, 512))
pygame.display.set_caption('Endlace')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

### Настраиваем директории ###
rootPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
resourcesPath = os.path.join(rootPath, "resources")
texturesPath = os.path.join(resourcesPath, "textures")
playerPath = os.path.join(texturesPath, "player")
skinsPath = os.path.join(playerPath, "skins")
defaultIdle = os.path.join(skinsPath, "default-idle")
defaultRun = os.path.join(skinsPath, "default-run")

### Настраиваем пути текстур ###
ground512 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(texturesPath, "ground512x512.png"))
box = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(texturesPath, "normalbox.png"))
box = pygame.transform.scale(box, (64, 64))
playerShadow = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(playerPath, "shadow.png"))
playerShadow = pygame.transform.scale(playerShadow, (64,64))
boxSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
boxSprite.image = box
boxSprite.rect = box.get_rect()

### Настраиваем шрифт ###
font1 = pygame.font.Font('font.ttf', 36)

grid1 = pygame.Rect((0,0,64,64))
fakeScreen = screen.copy()
testSurface = pygame.Surface((512,512))

screenScrollX = 0
screenScrollY = 0

frameCount = 0

mapList = [[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], #layer 1
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
               
           [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], #layer 2
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
               
           [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], #layer 3
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
               
           [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], #layer 4
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],]

### Классы ###
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(defaultIdle, "frame1.png"))
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (64, 64))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (128,128)


    def moveRight(self):
        global screenScrollX
        if not self.rect.right > 512:
            self.rect.x += 4
            # screenScrollX -= 8
    
    def moveLeft(self):
        global screenScrollX
        if not self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.x -= 4
            # screenScrollX += 8
    
    def moveUp(self):
        global screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.y -= 4
            # screenScrollY += 8
    
    def moveDown(self):
        global screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            self.rect.y += 4
            # screenScrollY -= 8
    
    def moveLeftDown(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            if not self.rect.left < 0:
                self.rect.y += 4
                # screenScrollY -= 8
                self.rect.x -= 4
                # screenScrollX += 8

    def moveLeftUp(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.top < 0:
            if not self.rect.left < 0:
                self.rect.y -= 4
                # screenScrollY += 8
                self.rect.x -= 4
                # screenScrollX += 8

    def moveRightDown(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            if not self.rect.right > 512:
                self.rect.y += 4
                # screenScrollY -= 8
                self.rect.x += 4
                # screenScrollX -= 8

    def moveRightUp(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        self.rect.y -= 4
        # screenScrollY += 8
        self.rect.x += 4
        # screenScrollX -= 8


player = Player()
allSprites.add(player)

def mainMenu():
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)

        screen.fill((0,0,0))

        posX, posY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        
        pygame.display.flip()

def sandbox():
    global motion
    global frameCount
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        
        screen.fill((0,0,0))

        posX, posY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                motion = "stop"
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    boxSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
                    boxSprite.image = box
                    boxSprite.rect = box.get_rect()
                    print(int(posX/64))
                    print(int(posY/64))
                    clickX = int(posX/64)
                    clickY = int(posY/64)
                    # if mapList[0][clickX][clickY] == 1:
                    #   mapList[1][clickX][clickY] = 1
                    #   boxSprite.rect.x = (posX//64)*64
                    #   boxSprite.rect.y = (posY//64)*64-28
                    #   print(mapList)
                    #   allSprites.add(boxSprite)
                    # elif mapList[1][clickX][clickY] == 1:
                    #   mapList[2][clickX][clickY] = 1
                    #   boxSprite.rect.x = (posX//64)*64-58
                    #   print(mapList)
                    #   allSprites.add(boxSprite)
                    # elif mapList[2][clickX][clickY] == 1:
                    #   mapList[3][clickX][clickY] = 1
                    #   boxSprite.rect.x = (posX//64)*64-678
                    #   print(mapList)
                    #   allSprites.add(boxSprite)
                    # else:
                    #   mapList[0][clickX][clickY] = 1
                    #   boxSprite.rect.x = (posX//64)*64
                    #   boxSprite.rect.y = (posY//64)*64
                    #   print(mapList)
                    #   allSprites.add(boxSprite)
                    mapList[0][clickX][clickY] = 1
                    boxSprite.rect.x = (posX//64)*64
                    boxSprite.rect.y = (posY//64)*64
                    # print(mapList)
                    allSprites.add(boxSprite)
                
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        if frameCount + 1 >= 27:
            frameCount = 0

        #moving
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
            motion = "left"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
            motion = "right"
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
            motion = "up"
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
            motion = "down"
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[K_UP]:
            motion = "leftup"
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[K_DOWN]:
            motion = "leftdown"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[K_UP]:
            motion = "rightup"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[K_DOWN]:
            motion = "rightdown"

        if motion == "left":
            player.moveLeft()
            # fakeScreen.blit(player.images[frameCount//3], (player.rect.x,player.rect.y))
            # frameCount += 1
        if motion == "right":
            player.moveRight()
            # fakeScreen.blit(player.images[frameCount//3], (player.rect.x,player.rect.y))
            # frameCount += 1
        if motion == "up":
            player.moveUp()
            # fakeScreen.blit(player.images[frameCount//3], (player.rect.x,player.rect.y))
            # frameCount += 1
        if motion == "down":
            player.moveDown()
            # fakeScreen.blit(player.images[frameCount//3], (player.rect.x,player.rect.y))

        if motion == "leftup":
            player.moveLeftUp()
        if motion == "leftdown":
            player.moveLeftDown()
        if motion == "rightup":
            player.moveRightUp()
        if motion == "rightdown":   
            player.moveRightDown()

        if motion == "stop":
            pass
    
        # screen.blit(player, (0,0))
        fakeScreen.blit(ground512, (0,0))
        fakeScreen.blit(playerShadow, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y))
        allSprites.update()
        allSprites.draw(fakeScreen)
        text2 = font1.render(str(int(clock.get_fps())), False,
                  (255, 255, 255))
        fakeScreen.blit(text2, (0,0))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(fakeScreen, (512, 512)), (screenScrollX,screenScrollY))
        pygame.display.flip()

sandbox()
```

И мне захотелось реализовать систему коллизии с коробками, которые появляются по нажатии на любую свободную область, но так как игра показывается "сверху-вниз", то игрок, при коллизии с любой коробки с задней стороны, половина игрока должна быть спрятана за игроком. И возникает вопрос: как сделать так, что коллизия с коробкой происходила только после коллизии другого прямоугольника.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, проверяя каждый раз при перемещении игрока, накладывается ли игрок с одним с коробок, и если так и есть, то "отталкивать" игрока назад на столько же пикселей, сколько и скорость игрока.

```
def checkForCollision(self):
    isCollision = False

    for x in range(len(collisionRects)):
        isCollision = False

        if self.rect.colliderect(collisionRects[x]):
            isCollision = True

        if isCollision == True:
                break

    return isCollision
```